# in django how to add data from html table without using form.py

Tags: django

how to save data from html table in django without using form.py. I am currently creating table in html with add button and after adding all rows in table i want to save it but i am not using form.py only view.py,html,model.py
my view code is below
views.py

```
 school_name = request.POST['school_name']
 m_pass_out = request.POST['m_pass_out']
 medicalschool = MedicalSchool(school_name=school_name, m_pass_out=m_pass_out)
 medicalschool.save()
```

my model code is below
models.py

```
class DoctorProfile(models.Model):
user_guid = models.OneToOneField(
    'EgdEradUsers', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='user_guid', primary_key=True)
doctor_guid = models.UUIDField(unique=True)
featured_doctor_id = models.BooleanField()
primary_speciality = models.ForeignKey(DSpecialtyType, models.DO_NOTHING)
# This field type is a guess.
secondary_speciality = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
years_experience = models.IntegerField()
# This field type is a guess.
education = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
license_number = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
npi_number = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
revalidation_cme = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
# This field type is a guess.
states_to_practice = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
# This field type is a guess.
board_certification = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
# This field type is a guess.
honors_awards_recognition = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
# This field type is a guess.
publications = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
# This field type is a guess.
hospital_privileges = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
phone_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
primary_contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=45)
phone_code2 = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
secondary_contact_number = models.CharField(
    max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
resume_url = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
avatar_url = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
additional_comments = models.CharField(
    max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'doctor_profile'

class MedicalSchool(models.Model):
school_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
m_pass_out = models.DateField(max_length=100)
doctor_profile = models.ForeignKey(DoctorProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
created_at = models.DateTimeField()
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'medical_school'
```

my html code is below
html

```
                    <div class="container-lg">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <div class="table-wrapper">
                            <div class="table-title">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <h2>Medical School</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <button type="button" id="medical" class="btn btn-info add- 
                                          new"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <table id="medicaltable" class="table table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Name of School</th>
                                        <th>Year of Graduation</th>
                                        <th>Actions</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td  id="medicaltext" name="school_name"></td>
                                        <td  id="medicaldate"  name="m_pass_out"></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a id="medicaladd" class="add" title="Add" data- 
                                          toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                                            <a id="medicaledit" class="edit" title="Edit" data- 
                                          toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                                            <a id="medicaldelete" class="delete" title="Delete" data- 
                                          toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: It does not make much sense not to use a form. You do not need to render a HTML form to work with a Django form. The idea of a Django form is to validate and clean data and remove a lot of boilerplate logic.

Comment: I didn't use the form for the rest of my app; that's why I am trying to avoid the form

Comment: but that doesn't sound like a good argument. Imagine that you need toe primary key of a school, but somehow some schools are not allowed, with a Django form that is easy to validate (in fact you do not need to write that logic, it is simply altering the `queryset=...`. By doing this manually, you will eventually have a large codebase, and if you later change your mind, it will take a lot of effort to change that codebase.

Comment: can I use the form only here so that I don't need to rewrite my whole code for only one table??

Comment: share DoctorProfile model too

Comment: just added doctorprofile model

Comment: i just want to get your doctor profile name to show in html. i think you can do it yourself. i commented where you should change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access to your each html form inputs by their name in view. see below code:

**models**

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

class MedicalSchool(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    m_pass_out = models.DateField(max_length=100)
    doctor_profile = models.ForeignKey(DoctorProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'medical_school'

class MedicalSchoolForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MedicalSchool
        fields = ['school_name', 'm_pass_out', 'doctor_profile']
```

**views**

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from . import models

def MedicalSchool(request):
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')  # get last url
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = models.MedicalSchoolForm(request.POST) # access to ModelForm
        if form.is_valid():
        data = models.MedicalSchool() # create a instance of your Model
        data.school_name = form.cleaned_data['school_name'] # 'school_name' is the name that we specified in html form input
        data.m_pass_out = form.cleaned_data['m_pass_out'] # 'm_pass_out' is the name that we specified in html form input
        data.doctor_profile_id = form.cleaned_data['doctor_profile'] # 'doctor_profile' is the name that we specified in html form input
        data.save()
        return redirect(url)
    else:
        messages.warning(request, form.errors)
        return redirect(url)
    context = {'DoctorProfile': models.DoctorProfile.objects.all()}
return render(request, 'MedicalSchool.html', context)
```

**urls**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'School'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.MedicalSchool, name='MedicalSchool'),
    ...
]
```

**MedicalSchool.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'School:MedicalSchool' %}" method="POST"> 
{% csrf_token %}

<input type="text" name="school_name" placeholder="school name" required>
<input type="text" name="m_pass_out" placeholder="m pass out" required>

<select name='doctor_profile'>
    {% for dr in DoctorProfile %}
        <option name="doctor_profile" value="{{ dr.id }}">{{ dr.title}}</option>  <!-- Match your code with {{ dr.title}} -->
    {% endfor %}
</select>

<button type="submit"> Submit </button>

</form>
```

> **let me know if there was a problem**

Comment: there  will be multiple schools in school so I need to save multiple rows

Comment: which model are you talking about?

Comment: One doctor could have gone to multiple medical school so i need to save 1 or more medical school information from that specific doctor

Comment: in MedicalSchool Model, doctor_profile field have foreign key to DoctorProfile Model. so MedicalSchool Form can just save for a specific DoctorProfile Model. this question is for MedicalSchool Form not for DoctorProfile Form. true?

Comment: if this question answered and you have another question. you can open another question and close this one

Comment: correct this question is for medical school and i was thinking that can I add data from the table to the model without using the form

Comment: if you want your data provided by user, you have to use form